# C# How do I pass object back to main thread from worker thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How do I handle data returned from a worker thread public method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the worker thread is a `Task<TResult>`, then you can retrieve the result from the `Task<TResult>.Result` property.

If the worker thread is a `BackgroundWorker`, then you can retrieve the result from the 
`RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result` property in the argument object passed to `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted`.

If the worker thread is a `ThreadPool` thread executed via `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, then you can retrieve the result by calling `EndInvoke`, even if the delegate has already completed.

If the worker thread is a `Thread`, or a `ThreadPool` thread executed via `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, then you must "return" the result by setting a subobject of a parameter, by using a lambda-bound variable, or by using a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how the thread was created and what kind of thread the main thread is.  If it's a WinForms or WPF thread the most straight forward way is to use the `SynchronizationContext` of the main thread to perform an operation back on the main thread once the worker thread is completed.

```
void StartWorker() {
  var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WorkerThread, context);
}

void WorkerThread(object state) {
  var context = (SynchronizationContext)state;
  ...;
  context.Post(WorkerDone, ...);
}

void WorkerDone(object state) {
  // back on UI thread
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
What is the main thread?
What is it doing with the data?

In WinForms, for example, you can call the `Invoke` method to run a callback on the main thread with the data as a parameter.